# puppeteer in angular - to print pdf

Tags: node.js, angular, pdf-generation, node-modules, puppeteer

I am trying to print pdf( convert html page to a pdf) in an Angular 9 application. I used puppeteer to accomplish the same - but running into issues -

Below is my code

```
exportPdf(){
    const url = window.location.href;
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true});
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(url);
      await page.pdf({path:'medium.pdf'});
      await browser.close();
    })();

  }
```

the above function is called from an angular template ( via a button click). I ran into the following issues, have solved them with the solution listed -

1. Can't resolve 'ws' - I installed ws via npm install and modified the WebSocketTransport.js to read from - node_modules/ws

```
const WebSocket = require('../node_modules/ws'); --> after adding the path error disappeared
const WebSocket = require('ws') --> this was not working
```

2. I got undefined errors for 'global' , 'buffer' and 'process' variables - I added shims for it in my polyfill.ts file

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
(window as any).process = {
    version: ''
  };
```

3. Now after all this when I run I am still getting the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PUPPETEER_PRODUCT' of undefined
    at Launcher (Launcher.js:855)
    at Object.get _launcher [as _launcher] (Puppeteer.js:63)
    at Object.get (<anonymous>)
    at Function.installAsyncStackHooks (helper.js:106)
    at Object../node_modules/puppeteer/index.js (index.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/shared/export-pdf/export-pdf.component.ts (tooltip.directive.ts:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/shared/shared.module.ts (shared.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
```

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody pls help out on this? Thanks much

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Did anyone of you find a soluton?